# EditText to Int

Tags: java, android, integer, android-edittext, int

I'm new to Java and Android development so I decided to make a simple app that takes in two fields and puts them in a simple math equation. However I have to convert the EditText into Int before I can do any math with them, right?
In the XML file I have set both EditTexts to android:inputType="number".
My attempts have been like this:

> ```
>   final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.height);
>   String heightString = height.getText().toString();
>   final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(heightString);
> ```

and

> ```
>   final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.height);
>   final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
> ```

I also tried Integer.valueOf in both cases but it always force closes my app when I run it and if I comment out that int heightInt it doesn't force close.

Here's the whole code:

> package com.body.calculator;
>
> ```
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.os.Vibrator;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class bmi extends Activity {
>      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>
>
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     final TextView results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results);
>     final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.height);
>     String heightString = height.getText().toString();
>     final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(heightString);
>     final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.weight);
>     final Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
>     Button submit_bmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_bmi);
>     submit_bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             if (height.getText().toString().equals("") && weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
>                 results.setText("Both fields are empty");
>                 vib.vibrate(100);
>             }
>             else if (height.getText().toString().equals("")) {
>                 results.setText("Height is empty");
>                 vib.vibrate(100);
>             }
>             else if (weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {
>                 results.setText("Weight is empty");
>                 vib.vibrate(100);
>             }
>             else {
>             results.setText("");    
>             }
>         }
>
>
>     });
>
> }
> }
> ```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks, Arnar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You approach of

```
  final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.height);
  String heightString = height.getText().toString();
  final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(heightString);
```

is correct, but you are calling this directly in your `onCreate` method. This means they get called as soon as the app starts, even before the user is able to do anything. because of this the values are always empty, simply because the user hasn't even had the change to do anything yet.

When you use the values later in your `onClick`(which is correct), they are still empty due to their early initialization.

Try putting this part:

```
String heightString = height.getText().toString();
final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(heightString);
```

Directly after the start of your `onClick` method but before your `if/else` statements like so:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String heightString = height.getText().toString();
    final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(heightString);

           // Your statements

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, should have seen that :/ However, now it force closes when I press the submit button.

Comment: I put the code in Try-Catch and it outputs "java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse ' ' as integer" when the edittexts are empty (as expected) but I'm unable to produce any error if I put something in the EditTexts.

Comment: I'm sorry for spamming the comments but I managed to find what is force closing it now. If I set results.setText("no force-close"); results change to "no force-close" but if I set results.setText(heightInt); I get a force close. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check your LogCat after you received the error? Most likely heightInt is empty when you try to set the result, resulting in a null pointer which force-closes your app.

Comment: It worked after I converted the int to string and put that in the setText(). However, now I am facing another problem. For this formula to work height has to be in cm. If I put commas in the EditText I get error about that Int doesn't like that. So if I put mm (180mm for example) and try to convert it to cm (180/100) I only get 1 not 1.8. What other way could I get mm to cm?

Comment: `Integers` are round numbers. They are always rounded down. What you are looking for, are `doubles`. These take fragmented numbers such as 1,8.  Try using `doubles` for you calculation.

Comment: Okay, I've got this now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can be happening (to know exactly what, you can look at the logcat output to see if an exception is being thrown). My guesses based on the info you gave are:

1. findViewById is returning null, and then you're trying to use the return value, causing a NPE.
2. Integer.parseInt is throwing an exception. It does that when it can't parse the string into a number. You should check that with try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parse the content on the EditText in `onCreate`. I guess that the EditText is empty at this moment, so the parsing, as indicated in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), throws a NumberFormatException. I guess you should only parse the content of the EditText in the onClick method, when the user submits.

I don't know how an EditText works, but if the user is allowed to enter something other than an integer in the EditText, you should catch NumberFormatException to avoid an exception to be thrown.

Note that your two code snippets do exactly the same thing. The first one just stores the content of the EditText in a local variable before parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment of `heightInt` and `weightInt` into onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

i solved the same problem,
put these lines in try and catch block

```
String heightString = height.getText().toString();
final int heightInt = Integer.parseInt(heightString);
```

run the application,
In emulator,  there should be no space after enter the number

Answer (score 0):

```
btnFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double num1,num2,res;
                num1 = Double.valueOf(editFirst.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.valueOf(editSecond.getText().toString());
                res = num1 + num2;
                result.setText(""+res);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid putting some code without any explanation.